# Why do I get a "no such file or directory" error when the file is known to exist?

Tags: python, file, pypi

I have uploaded a package to pypi and [github](https://github.com/codophobia/pycricket/tree/master/pycricket). I have then installed the package and tried to use it. It contains a python script which need to read from a file. I have placed both in the same directory.

```
pip install pycricket

from pycricket import cricket
c = cricket.Cricket()
c.query()
```

Query() function involves reading from a file. When I see the 'pycricket' package in library, both script as well as file are in same folder.

```
query():
   with open('matches.csv', 'r') as f:
   #code
```

I don't know why I get the error.

Comment: Because it's not in the current working directory.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You mean the directory in which I am running the above code or in the library directory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you suggest a solution for it?

Comment: Make sure that the file is in the current working directory.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I want the file to be in the library.

Comment: So then put the path.

Comment: Import OS lib, and put your file directory in os.chdir('your folder path not file'), like this :                                                  


query():

   os.chdir('your path')

   with open('matches.csv', 'r') as f:

   #Code

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the current working directory with:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
```

If your data is in a different directory (unclear from the question, but likely given the error message), then change to the directory where the data is stores:

```
>>> os.chdir(path_to_data_directory)
```